# STRING_SPLIT with multi delimiter in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to split values based on multiple values like ',' & 'And', operators. But I used 'And' in split function it is not working, can someone help me to achieve this?

```
select distinct y.value from  history x
 cross apply STRING_SPLIT(x.query, ',') y 
where lower(rtrim(ltrim(y.value))) not in (
    select s.value from keys s cross apply STRING_SPLIT(y.value, 'And') z where lower((s.value)) like lower(rtrim(ltrim(z.value)))
);
```

> Msg 214, Level 16, State 11, Line 23
>   Procedure expects parameter 'separator' of type 'nchar(1)/nvarchar(1)'.

**Sample input Data:**

```
student,teacher,tutor and principle and director
```

**Output:**

```
student
teacher
tutor
principle
director
```

Comment: Please include some sample data.  There might another way to go about doing this.

Comment: updated with sample data

Comment: If "and" is the only word that is present in your input, then simply do a replace of And with a comma and then do a string split

Comment: @Harry That sounds like a good answer to me :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "and" is the only word that is present in your input, then simply do a replace of And with a comma and then do a string split